# Need help hosting a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, publish

First things first, I want to say that I have absolutely zero experience in publishing applications.

I finished a project for my first client (ASP.NET Core 6, EF Core, MailKit, AzureBlob and other NuGet packages), bought a domain and a 3rd party hosting plan (Hostinger).

Today I tried all day to publish the app and I can't wrap my head around tutorials. The publish results didn't look like a website structure (no html, css, js), I had a bunch of folders named "ar", "af". "bn-BD" etc, a bunch of dlls and a `MVCCore.exe` (the name of the `project.exe` basically).

I searched the whole internet, even reached 3'rd google page, what am I doing wrong?

I'm also in a time crisis because the client wants the app up and running by 28'th this month.

Any help received would be rewarded with a warm hug.

**TL:TR** : How should I straight up publish a ASP.NET Core MVC application?

I tried publishing the app in a folder and through a FTP client (same results as said above)

Comment: Have you 1) checked if `wwwroot` folder is present in the publish folder 2) tried running the app from the folder  ?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy) certainly looks like a good place to start.  Does your host support ASP.NET Core web applications?  Do they offer any information on how to publish to their server?

Answer (score 2):

> The publish results didn't look like a website structure (no html, css, js)

The content files (html, css, js, images) should be present in the `wwwroot` folder

> I had a bunch of folders named "ar", "af". "bn-BD"

Those folders contain some culture-specific resources which may be used by your app

> a bunch of dlls and a MVCCore.exe

`MVCCore.exe` and `MVCCore.dll` are the files you can use to run your app (basically the contain the `Main` entry point method) the rest are the dlls coming from libraries and projects you have used to build your app.

Read more:

- [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (describes a bit the wwwroot)

P.S.

Based on what I got from the quick overview of the Hostinger it seems that it is primary Wordpress hosting platform and if you want to host ASP.NET Core site there you need to buy the VPS option there and setup everything on it ([link](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583610-do-you-support-asp-and-asp-net)). Taking in account that you have mentioned using AzureBlob maybe it will make more sense to host the app in Azure.

Comment: To give an extra note on the Azure suggestion. This will make your publish a whole lot easer as well in my experience